# "Access Denied" page ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to setup my "Access Denied" page

I use:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI ver. 8.0.0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore ver. 8.0.0
```

I try:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/AccessDenied";
    });
```

but when I try to open protected page

```
/Identity/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=
```

why so? What is necessary to change to `/account/AccessDenied` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you could modify the default Identity Access Denied page.

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/AccessDenied";
});
```

Or

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/AccessDenied";
});
```